# jQuery code to get desired picture

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im doing a web page for my school project. I want to have 2, lets call them selecting tabs, first one contains some colors and second one pictues of wheels for a car. I have 25 pictures of one car with 5 diferent wheels and 5 diferent colors. I want to make 2 drop down menus, one that lets me select one of those 5 colors I have, and second one to let me select one of 5 wheels I have and after selecting both of them, desired pictues apears with that car color and wheel.I want to somehow connect all of that by image name.

```
     var button_beg = '<button id="button" onclick="showhide()">', button_end = '</button>';
     var show_button = 'Show', hide_button = 'Hide';
     function showhide() {
         var div = document.getElementById("hide_show");
         var showhide = document.getElementById("showhide");
         if (div.style.display !== "none") {
             div.style.display = "none";
             button = show_button;
             showhide.innerHTML = button_beg + button + button_end;
         } else {
             div.style.display = "block";
             button = hide_button;
             showhide.innerHTML = button_beg + button + button_end;
         }
     }

    function setup_button(status) {
        if (status == 'show') {
            button = hide_button;
        } else {
            button = show_button;
        }
        var showhide = document.getElementById("showhide");
        showhide.innerHTML = button_beg + button + button_end;
    }
    window.onload = function () {
        setup_button('hide');
        showhide(); // if setup_button is set to 'show' comment this line
    }
```

I tried this code with javascript but its not working for me as It should. Anybody knows how to exactly write the code with `jQuery` to get those 2 drop down menus and to select items?

Comment: not sure what you are trying to do. Can you put your code in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: I haven't read your code, just the description and I think the most easiest way to achive this is to rename the picture: `carcolor_wheelcolor.jpg`, once the user select the two colors, you combine the values in that way and then change the image `src`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't now what your code does, but it doesn't related to the question, however...
Let's suppose this is your HTML and that images are saved as `carcolor_wheelscolor.png`:

```
<button id="button">Change</button>car color:
<select id='carcol'>
    <option value='red'>red</option>
    <option value='blue'>blue</option>
    <option value='green'>green</option>
</select>Wheels color:
<select id='wheelcol'>
    <option value='red'>red</option>
    <option value='blue'>blue</option>
    <option value='green'>green</option>
</select>
<div class='df'>
</div>
```

Then you can achive what your are asking in this way:

```
$('#button').click(function(){
    var carcol= $('#carcol').val(),
        wheelcol=$('#wheelcol').val(),
        imageSrc = "/path/to/images/" + carcol + '_' + wheelcol + '.png';
    if ($('img.carImage').length)
        $('img.carImage').attr('src ',imageSrc);
    else
        $('.df').append('<img class="carImage" src="' + imageSrc + '"/>');
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ofj1bbbn/4/)

With pure js(**edit** fixed):

```
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener("click",function(){
    var carcol= document.getElementById('carcol').value,
        wheelcol=document.getElementById('wheelcol').value,
        imageSrc = "/path/to/images/" + carcol + '_' + wheelcol + '.png';
    if (document.getElementsByClassName('carImage')[0]){
        document.getElementsByClassName('carImage')[0].setAttribute('src',imageSrc);
    }
    else{
        var el=document.createElement("img");
        el.setAttribute('class','carImage');
        el.setAttribute('src',imageSrc);
        document.getElementsByClassName('df')[0].appendChild(el);
    }
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ofj1bbbn/8/)

Comment: So I tried this, first in demo, in demo, when I click Change button an image appears, but in my web page cant get it to work. Copied all text, changed image source to mine, named images and used javascrpit and jquery-2.1.4.min.js in the script type. Anything I missed or did wrong?

Comment: Add your html to your question

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ofj1bbbn/5/  I tried this, but now I see that it doesnt work in fiddle, did I messed up something with image src?

Comment: It works for me(the image is broken because the src doesn't exist), have added a div to append the image? In my example I have: `<div class='df'></div>`

Comment: yes, I have the div, idk why it doesnt work, I copied you code, changed img src to folder named images and named one picture green_greento try it  but even that doesnt work.

Comment: I think it's better if you add your html to your main question, however you need ot check: `selector` `id`, must be the same, the `div class` and the `button` `id`, try also to remove any other `onclick` event from the button, place the `script` at the bottom of the page

Comment: got it working now, tnx for help on this Razorphyn ;)

Comment: If it was usefull remember to accept this post as answer, thanks

Comment: Just one more question, after you pick car and wheel color, can you then pick another wheel color and press change, does it then refresh the picture?

Comment: @slamek10 Ok fixed them and corrected the procedure to add the img tag, now it works and yes, it will change the image